# Difference between Auth0(Angularjs Auth0) , Satellizer and ng-token-auth

Tags: angularjs, openid-connect, auth0, satellizer

I currently have an Open Id Authentication implementation setup and deployed. I have a JAVA Rest API(Resource server) and have an angularjs application working. The issue I am facing is to trigger authentication from the angularjs app to the Open Id Connect auth server and get the access token back and pass it to the Java Rest Api to introspect at the Authentication server and get the user details.

I have come across these 3 libraries and was confused as to the difference between them.

1) [Angularjs_Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular)

2) [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

3) [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth)

Any advice as to how to configure the auth provider in these tools would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can speak of Auth0 (disclaimer: I work there).

You could use the auth0-angular library with your openid connect implementation since we are OpenID Connect compatible. I've never tried it with an OIDC server that is not Auth0, but it should work.

You might want to include auth0.js (https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js) which implements the "protocol". auth0-angular is just a wrapper with more higher level functions.

```
authProvider.init({
      domain: 'youropenidconnectserver.com',
      clientID: 'your-clientid',
      loginUrl: '/login'
    });
```

Let me know if it worked fine. If you need a higher bandwidth conversation we are on Slack (http://chat.auth0.com)

Hope this helps,
Matias

Comment: Hi Matias, Thanks for your prompt answer.I tried authentication with Auth0 but it doesn't work. My open id connect auth server is based on [MitreId Open ID Connect Implementation](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) and the api is /api/clients/{id}. The auth0 implementation uses auth0-lock.js line 1351 to get Client configuration and it is looking at this url this.$options.assetsUrl + 'client/' + this.$options.clientID + '.js' + '?t' + (+new Date()) which doesn't exist in the above open id connect implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with my own implementation. made the resource server as the client and redirecting to resource server page to trigger the login process of Open Id Connect.Only issue is I am redirecting back to angularjs app but am not able to get the token back.